# Mostrar todos os arquivos do banco de dados em uma página php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Galera, fiz esse código para exibir todos os arquivos que foram anexados pelo usuário, porém ele apenas mostra o arquivo com o menor ID, ou seja, o primeiro arquivos no banco de dados. Esse é o código que usei:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="tittlenoticia" style="color: black;">Arquivos anexados</h1>
       <?php
       require_once('conecta.php');
       $pasta = "uploads/";
       $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
        var_dump($consulta);
       if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
          do {
            echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . "\">" . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
          }
          while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta));
        } 
       ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Eu fiz o var_dump da variável `$consulta` e apareceu o seguinte:

`object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(9) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Alguém tem alguma ideia de porque ele não mostra os outros arquivos? E mais uma coisa, esse código php apenas é executado se eu enviar um arquivo, mas eu queria que fosse executado ao iniciar a página, se tiverem alguma ideia também fico agradecido!

Comment: Se você executar diretamente no SGBD a consulta, irá te retornar todos os arquivos do usuário?

Comment: @GabrielHeming Sim, retorna todos os arquivos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está ocorrendo por causa de um "typo".

Veja, para abrir a consulta, está utilizando:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
```

Entretanto, no `do/while`, está utilizando

```
while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta));
```

Está misturando `mysqli` com funções `mysql_*`. Deveria utilizar apenas `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Para simplificar as coisas, faça o `while` direto, não terá problemas:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . "\">" . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
}
```

Além do mais, no seu `if` não há `else`.

Comment: Cara, era realmente isso, eu comecei a usar mysqli agora, sempre esqueço desse i. E tem algum problema se deixar o if sem o else?

Comment: @ArthurOliveira Não há problema, mas o código é redundante, ou seja, está escrevendo mais código para ter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Entendido, e você tem alguma ideia de como fazer esse código ser executado ao iniciar a página? Porque ele só executa quando eu anexo um arquivo e clico em enviar.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira como assim? Em teoria, se a página está sendo chamada, ele já é executado automaticamente. Entretanto, acredito que esse seu questionamento deva ser feita como outra pergunta.

Comment: É o que eu achava também, mas ele só executa se anexar um arquivo. Eu vou fazer esse questionamento como outra pergunta então, muito obrigado pela ajuda, agradeço demais!!